# what does `client_id` mean in password credentials grant of OAuth 2.0?

Tags: authentication, oauth

Public clients can't hide their requests. So password credentials grant doesn't need `clientSecret`. What I'm curious is, is there need `client_id`? because hacker or client user can know or trace the client_id and make same request easily. Public clients like mobile app or web app can't guarantee of that is confidential client.

I really want to know how public clients solve this. Such as Facebook mobile app and Google Inbox. They implemented authentication way for themsevles? Drop out OAuth 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:
`client_id` and `client_secret` are used for to authenticate the **`APP`**.
`username` and `password` are used for to authenticate the **`user`**.

It also means double layer protection.

The [specification](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-27.html#rfc.section.4.3)  says:

> the client MUST authenticate with the authorization server as described in [Section 3.2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-27.html#token-endpoint-auth).

A client authentication is done by using a `client_id` and a `client_secret` value.

Actually the latest paragraph of the section 3.2.1 says

> A public client that was not issued a client password MAY use the client_id request parameter to identify itself when sending requests to the token endpoint (e.g. for the purpose of providing end-user context, client usage statistics).

However, it just may.
But Google gives a `client_id` and a `client_secret` on [the developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) when trying to use an API.

If you want to use `Resource Owner Password Credentials` for an API or a Web authorization you might provide [a register page](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-27.html#rfc.section.2) to your clients to register themselves. (I recommend using of [Client Credentials flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-41) for API)

If you want to use `Resource Owner Password Credentials` for a mobile app you might give a standart `client_id` like `AwesomeAPP` and a `client_secret` like `Bl**123_Blabla`.

Or you may use  `AwesomeAPP_v1.0`  as `client_id` to track that how many people use which version of the App although it's not the best way. But you may.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I was just confused. `clientID` and `clientPassword` shouldn't be in public clients... Anyway Thank you!

Comment: I had thought just like you and I agree with you about public clients. However, if we talk about a mobile app `client_id` and `client_secret` values will be compiled in the app. Also it had taken my time a lot because of client registration works, learning OAuth 2.0 flows and PassportJS etc. Good luck...